# Erro com wxWidgets wxmsw30u_gcc_custom.dll

Tags: dll, wxwidgets, codeblocks

http://prnt.sc/8lfnv5
Estou iniciando com C/C++ e peguei o code::blocks como compilador, estou querendo usar o wxWidgets, compilei uma aplicação, um hello world, ao abrir pelo code::blocks ela funciona normal, quando tento abrir direto do ".exe", da o erro da print, peço ajuda a vocês.

Comment: Olá, seja bem vindo!

Para que a comunidade possa ajuda-lo é interessante que você poste o código, assim a descrição fica mais completa.

Comment: Muito obrigado David, eu só selecionei o projeto de wxWidgets no code::blocks, dai já veio com um código de hello world, só fiz compilar para testar, eu compilei o wxWidgets por esse tutorial aqui: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgAaiBg4wEE.

    Aqui vai o código:    

OTCMakerApp.cpp
http://pastebin.com/Kmd9K8rw
OTCMakerMain.cpp
http://pastebin.com/e3LtasQq
OTCMakerApp.h
http://pastebin.com/NHShxCu5
OTCMakerMain.h
http://pastebin.com/cTxFMCtX

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa colocar essa DLL na pasta do programa, caso não queira fazer isso, você pode por a DLL na pasta "C:\Windows\System32" ou na "C:\Windows\SysWOW64", na duvida coloque nas duas pastas.

Essa DLL está localizada na pasta da biblioteca, que nesse caso é a Wxwidgets.